# Can you identify the chinese writing on the bottom of a bowl?

Tags: character-identification

This is on the bottom of a Chinese bowl:

[image]

Comment: It's upside down, and extremely blurry.

Comment: Please politely accept the correct answer as an appreciation of the responder's effort and time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll turn it around, I can't undo the blurry however

Comment: How would I find out if this is not a fake/real? I am in the Seattle area, anyplace there?

Answer (score 3):

rotate the photo 180 °, make it upside down, one can read it as:

“成化年製”

it means roughly “made during 1465-1487”

Comment: Does this mean the bowl is that old?

Comment: @SherriAndres Yes, if it is not fake.